# True?: Let $(n, m)$ be an arbitrary Amicable Pair. Then $n$ is odd iff its last digit is $5$

Tags: number-theory

I believe I've found all Amicable Pairs $(n, m)$ such that n is in the closed interval $[1, 34000000]$. Here's my [list](http://tutoree7.pastebin.com/fg3mVNmF).

By inspection I believe that for all $n$ in the list, $n$ is odd iff its last digit is $5$. Can it be proved that this is true for all Amicable Pairs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the first counterexample $(n,m)$ with $n < m$ where $n$ is odd and not congruent to $5$ mod $10$ is $(34765731, 36939357)$, which by misfortune is just outside your search region.

Comment: Damn. You're right. Thanks. BTW I'm rusty. Could you spell out the terminology in "not congruent to 5 mod 10"? Thanks.

Comment: In this case, just "doesn't end w/5", but seems less base-related.. :^)  See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks. Good article. It's coming back, slowly.

Answer (score 1):

How about 87633 and 69615?  Found 87633 in [OEIS A063990](http://oeis.org/A063990)

Comment: I neglected to say that n < m. The n of the pair (69615, 87633) is odd and ends in '5'.