# Odd amicable pairs

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was curious if there are odd amicable pairs such that both do not have a 5 in the ones digit? I apologize if it's easy to find one with a computer I'm not that smooth

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/true-let-n-m-be-an-arbitrary-amicable-pair-then-n-is-odd-iff-its-last?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you Dietrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found such two pairs with PARI/GP : $$[34765731, 36939357]$$ and $$[136549413, 140207067]$$

Comment: A third solution is $$[346657311, 370393569]$$

Comment: And the last solution upto $10^9$ is $$[664747083, 673747893]$$